# retrieving data from server on phonegap

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, cordova, backend

I dunno if I'm asking this question right.
But basicly I'm making a Computer based test app. And I want to make a mobile app for it. So what I just require is knowledge on how to retrieve and send data to my mysql database. I can't use php since phonegap doesn't support it. So how can I successfully integrate a phone gap app written in js with my backend mysql database.
Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Two appraches I tested and both worked out well:

#### 1. Communication via HTTP requests.

This simple approch allows you to communicate with basically any server side implementation; you could therefore theoretically use a php-server to communicate with your database (PHP code reads get/post request, makes database stuff and then echo's the response).

However, using a `Servlet` might be the easier approach.

#### 2. List Write your own communication plugin.

This is definitely the harder approch and therefore I won't recommend it. However, this would still not allow you to use php on client-side.

Note: I write my JavaScript code using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/). Therefore `HTTPRequests` are made easily.